# Como ordenar un string con método de la burbuja

Tags: c#

Como hago para que los nombres me queden ordenados junto con los sueldos correspondientes a cada sueldo.

```
using System;

namespace Proyecto_Final
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n_Empleados, i, j;
            double suma;

            Console.Write("Digite el numero de empleados que desea evaluar : ");
            n_Empleados = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();
            double[] sueldo_tot = new double[n_Empleados];

            string[] nombre = new String[n_Empleados];

            double[,] sueldo = new double[n_Empleados, 5];


            for (i = 0; i < nombre.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Nombre del empleado" + (i + 1) + " : ");
                nombre[i] = Console.ReadLine();

                suma = 0; //EL ACOUMLADOR REGRESARA A 0 POR CADA EMPLEADO

                for (j = 0; j < sueldo.GetLength(1); j++)//El metodo GetLengh se utiliza para conocer la dimension para una matriz (0) para fila y (1) para conocer el de columnas
                {
                    Console.Write("Sueldo del mes " + (j + 1) + " del Empleado/a " + nombre[i] + " : ");
                    sueldo[i, j] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    suma = suma + sueldo[i, j];

                }
                sueldo_tot[i] = suma;//Igualamos el vector sueldo_tot con suma para guardar los sueldos.
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Clear();
            }

            Imprimir_Suma_Sueldo(sueldo_tot, nombre);


            Empleado_Mayor(sueldo_tot, nombre);
            Console.WriteLine("***Ordenacion de los sueldos***");
            Fin_Metodo_Burbuja(sueldo_tot, nombre);//Fin del metodo de la burbuja 
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static void Imprimir_Suma_Sueldo(double[] sueldostot, string[] nom_Emp)
        {
            int i;

            Console.WriteLine("Total de sueldos pagados por empleado.");

            for (i = 0; i < sueldostot.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write((i+1)+" "+nom_Emp[i] + " - " + sueldostot[i]);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        static void Empleado_Mayor(double[] sueldos, string[] nom_Empleados)
        {
            //Las variables mayor y nombres se igualan al los arreglos ya utilizados en main, estos arreglos se igualaran 0
            double mayor = sueldos[0];
            string nombres = nom_Empleados[0];

            int i;

            for (i = 0; i < sueldos.Length; i++)
            {
                if (sueldos[i] > mayor)
                {
                    mayor = sueldos[i];
                    nombres = nom_Empleados[i];
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("El empleado con mayor sueldo es " + nombres + " que tiene un sueldo de " + mayor);
        } 


        static void Fin_Metodo_Burbuja(double[] sueldo, string[] nombre)
        {
            //Metodo de la burbuja
            int i, j;
            double mb;
            for (i = 0; i < sueldo.Length; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < sueldo.Length - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (sueldo[i] > sueldo[j])
                    {
                        mb = sueldo[i];
                        sueldo[i] = sueldo[j];
                        sueldo[j] = mb;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < sueldo.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}.- {1}", nombre[i], sueldo[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Actualmente cual es el problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El ordenamiento está bien, pero solo estas ordenando el array de sueldos totales y no el de nombres. Deberías ordenar los dos a la par para no perder la relación uno a uno:

```
static void Fin_Metodo_Burbuja(double[] sueldo, string[] nombre)
{
    //Metodo de la burbuja
    int i, j;
    double mb;
    string mbNombre;
    for (i = 0; i < sueldo.Length; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < sueldo.Length - 1; j++)
        {
            if (sueldo[i] > sueldo[j])
            {
                //sueldo
                mb = sueldo[i];
                sueldo[i] = sueldo[j];
                sueldo[j] = mb;
                 //nombre
                mbNombre = nombre[i];
                nombre[i] = nombre[j];
                nombre[j] = mbNombre;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < sueldo.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}.- {1}", nombre[i], sueldo[i]);
    }
}
```